# Moving JFrame with arrow keys?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I want a normal JFrame that moves across the screen keys.
It turns out not all that easy.

For some reason I get a rough code e.getKeyChar ()

It is even possible? I think that we have to somehow rewrite techniques, since I started, but there is something wrong.

Prompt, adjust -

```
public class Main implements Runnable {
    private int xLocation = 200;
    private int yLocation = 200;
    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Main());
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Label"));
        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Close") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(xLocation, yLocation);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher, KeyListener {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

            char key = e.getKeyChar();

            if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            }
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                //System.out.println("tester");
            } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                //System.out.println("2test2");
            } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
                //System.out.println("3test3");
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("e.getKeyChar() " + e.getKeyChar());
            char key = e.getKeyChar();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                xLocation += 5;
            }
            frame.setLocation(xLocation, yLocation);
            frame.repaint();            
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.getRootPane().getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED), "moveRight");
    jFrame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("moveRight", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jFrame.setLocation(jFrame.getX() + 5, jFrame.getY());
        }
    });
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

If you have ancestors inside your `JFrame` than you should take the `InputMap/ActionMap` approach. See the official [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).